# Shift the concentric circle and coordinate to the right

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry

```
clc
n=10;
th=(0:360)*pi/180;
h=axes('Position',[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]);
hold on
cc='bmmyyyggwr';

for i=1:n

    x=(n+1-i)*cos(th);
    y=(n+1-i)*sin(th);

    plot(x,y);   
    fill(x,y,cc(i))
    axis off
    axis equal

end
```

I plot 10 concentric circles. I want the concentric circle and coordinate keep moving to right along the X-axis, and stay a while during shifting.

I used the plot(x+20,y),but it can't move color. How to make the concentric circles stay for a while during shifting? Really appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Do you want to change the `x` coordinates in the loop? Try `plot(x+i, y)`. Do you want a pause after each step? Try `pause(1)` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it still doesn't work. I want the whole graph and coordinate shift to right. The graph will stop for a while during the shift.

Comment: Just to make sure... you want to plot all circles as in your code snippet above, and then move the circles along the x axis with a pause for each step?

Comment: Yes! I want 10 circles move at same time and along the x axis with a pause for each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do what you want.
Note we're setting `xlim` and `ylim`, otherwise the circles would not appear to move at all. In the first loop, we draw the circles, in the second loop, we move them.

```
clf
n=10;
th=(0:360)*pi/180;
h=axes('Position',[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]);
hold on
cc='bmmyyyggwr';
phh = gobjects(2, n);
xlim([-10, 30])
ylim([-10, 10])
axis off
axis equal
for i=1:n

    x=(n+1-i)*cos(th);
    y=(n+1-i)*sin(th);

    phh(1, i)=plot(x,y);   
    phh(2, i)=fill(x,y,cc(i));    
end   
for j=1:n
    for i=1:n
        phh(1, i).XData = phh(1, i).XData + 1;
        phh(2, i).XData = phh(2, i).XData + 1;
    end
    drawnow
    pause(1);
end
```

Comment: Really appreciate for your help! It worked very well!